# Add to wishlist button not redirecting to login page while not logged in

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, wishlist

I have used "Magento ver. 1.9.2.1" in my website.

On product list and view page wishlist button working while customer logged in but if any customer not logged in then on click wishlist button it is not redirecting me to login page and showing error in log as shown in below figure :

[image]

I have checked it more than three PC but same issue occur.

Is there any setting in magento to remove this error and redirect to login page?

Comment: Go admin side : System -> Configuration -> Web (General tab left side) and check settings :
Browser Capabilities Detection :::
Redirect to CMS-page if Cookies are Disabled
& 
Show Notice if JavaScript is Disabled

Comment: Content highlighted is a standard Magento message for browsers having JS disabled. It is wrapped inside `<noscript></noscript>` tags on every page. That is not the issue. Check in the console tab instead, if you are having any errors in there.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it is not browser problem, I think there is magento setting because on another magento site I am redirecting to login page when click on add to wishlist button. And this content not showing me on page it is showing me on network log. Please reply if you have any solution.